# Pulse skip modulation vs Phase cutting for AC inductive loads?

Tags: microcontroller, ac, triac, pulse, phase

What is preferred and safe mode for controlling power to an Inductive AC load when driven by a Triac?

I am using a microcontroller with zero crossing optocoupler to drive the control signal and the load is Cieling fan.

If only one is suitable for it then what is the other method used for  ? Resistive loads?

Comment: Phase cutting is more accurate and has greater resolution than pulse skipping.

Comment: Inductive AC loads sometimes need frequency control rather than average voltage control.

Comment: @vini_i but is it safe for the equipment ? it can induce lot of switching noise

Comment: It then depends on what kind of inductive load you have. Inductive motors won't like anything other than frequency control. Universal wound motors generally tolerate it. Transformers don't care too mutch.